# lmRob() on mostly linear data: errors and defense

Tags: r

I am working with a legacy R script using `robust::lmRob()`.

The documentation for `lmRob()` is quite clear, and the example runs fine (for docs and example, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/robust/versions/0.4-16/topics/lmRob))

Based on that, I would have thought this simple script would work, but it fails with *'msg.UCV' not found*

```
library(robust)
xx = c(c(2.1111,3.1111,4.1111),seq(1,7,by=0.3))
yy = 0.5+1.5*xx 
yy[1] = -21; yy[2] = 0; yy[3] = -10
df = data.frame(x=xx,y=yy)

mf = lmRob(y~x, data=df)
```

Note that the data is 21 exactly linear rows, plus three outliers.

If instead one uses

```
yy = 0.5+1.5*xx + 0.01*xx^2
```

then no errors arise.

I would switch to `robustbase::lmrob()` but `lmRob.fit.compute()` seems to do some fairly [nontrivial things](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/R/lmRob.fit.compute.q?view=markup&root=robust&pathrev=34).

What is a good defensive programming technique to prevent near-linear data from causing errors in my program?

Comment: Can you play god a (tiny) bit and add some random noise to the points?